# Draw method doesn't get called from the custom UIView

Tags: ios, xamarin, uiview

I'm creating a custom map pin (annotation) for iOS, draw its path and then convert the `UIView` to an image, using this [method](https://gist.github.com/ozzieperez/85cf1d0bad627a6ab928):

```
public static UIImage AsImage(this UIView view)
{
    try
    {
        UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(view.Bounds.Size, true, 0);
        var ctx = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
        view.Layer.RenderInContext(ctx);
        var img = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
        return img;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and this is the `UIView`-derived class, where I draw the annotation path:

```
public class PinView : UIView
{
    public PinView()
    {
        ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.Redraw;
        SetNeedsDisplay();
    }
    private readonly CGPoint[] markerPathPoints = new[]
   {
        new CGPoint(25f, 5f),
        new CGPoint(125f, 5f),
        //other points    };

    public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
    {
        base.Draw(rect);
        //get graphics context
        CGContext context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
        //set up drawing attributes
        context.SetLineWidth(10);
        UIColor.White.SetFill();
        UIColor.Black.SetStroke();

        //create geometry
        var path = new CGPath();
        path.MoveToPoint(markerPathPoints[0].X, markerPathPoints[0].Y);
        for (var i = 1; i < markerPathPoints.Length; i++)
        {
            path.AddLineToPoint(markerPathPoints[i].X, markerPathPoints[i].Y);
        }

        path.CloseSubpath();
        //add geometry to graphics context and draw it
        context.AddPath(path);
        context.DrawPath(CGPathDrawingMode.FillStroke);
    }
```

I'm modifying the Xamarin.Forms [sample of the MapCustomRenderer](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/CustomRenderers/Map/Pin/iOS/CustomMapRenderer.cs#L64), instead of loading the annotation from a file, I'm loading it from the view:

```
annotationView.Image = new PinView().AsImage();
```

but the `PinView.Draw()` never get called!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The view needs to be added to the views hierarchy, in my case, to the `MKAnnotationView`,
so in the `CustomMKAnnotationView` constructor:

```
public CustomMKAnnotationView(IMKAnnotation annotation, string id)
    : base(annotation, id)
{
    var pin = new PinView(new CGRect(0, 0, 110, 110));
    pin.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White.ColorWithAlpha(0);
    Add(pin);
}
```

and in the `UIView`'s constructor, the `Frame` should be initialized as Lucas Zhang stated:

```
public PinView(CGRect rectangle)
{
    Frame = rectangle;
    ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.Redraw;
    SetNeedsDisplay();
}
```

With these changes the `Draw` method is called.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer , which will help more people :)

Comment: You could edit your answer with more details or edit my answer, maybe the two answers are similar.

Answer (score 1):

The method `Draw` will been invoked after the method `ViewDidLoad`when the control first been loaded , which is called automatically by the system .

In your case , you didn't set the Rect(Frame) of the `PinView` . So the method `Draw` will never been called because the `Rect` is zero in default .

So you could set a default frame in the constructor

```
public PinView()
{
  Frame = new CGRect (0,0,xx,xxx);
  ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.Redraw;
  SetNeedsDisplay();
}
```

Comment: Any idea why the view appears as a black box? no black colors defined, and the view works fine when passing to `SetNativeControl` of a custom control renderer

Comment: You could provide a sample which contains the issue so that I could test it on my side .

Comment: Thanks, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1itTEO68pHxri5RVswvGl6Gy1rQVOAB8L/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I think because of `UIColor.Black.SetStroke();
`

Comment: in the attached sample it should be `UIColor.Blue.SetStroke();`

Comment: I think `Draw` still not called :(